# Autofill and submit input fields outside form tag

Tags: javascript, html, forms, web-scraping

I'm working on autofilling a form for creating a Google MCC account:
https://adwords.google.com/um/Welcome/Home?a=1&sf=ms&authuser=0#ma

I planned to use robobrowser for that. I can see it's quite simple to set fields in a form if a form tag actually exists in the source code for the website, e.g.:

```
signup_form = browser.get_form(class_='signup')
signup_form['user[user_password]'].value = 'secret'
```

In this case however, all the input fields are not embraced by any form tag, e.g:

```
<input type="text" class="umMSB" placeholder="email@example.com" dir="ltr" aria-   invalid="false">
```

Is it still possible to auto populate these fields and submit them somehow?

Answer (score 0):

I tested out your code in RoboBrowser and if you `print browser.parsed` after opening the page, it appears to return mainly JavaScript, which RoboBrowser can't read.

Try Ghost.py